# What is the correct way to implement login with redirect using JSF 2.0?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

Part of my site should be accessible only to authorized users. Let's assume user would enter page a.html which belongs to the authorized-only part.

If I was to use servlets/JSP I could write a filter that checked whether user is logged in and if not - redirected him to login page. After a successful login user would be redirected to the page he wanted to reach initially, in this case a.html. (Page address could be stored in request).

What is a proper way to implement such scenario in JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it the same way, with a `Filter`. It's good to know that JSF session scoped managed beans are under the covers stored as a `HttpSession` attribute with the managed bean name as key.

Assuming that you've a managed bean like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped 
public class UserManager {

    private User user;

    // ...

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return (user != null);
    }

}
```

Then you can check it in `Filter#doFilter()` as follows:

```
UserManager userManager = (UserManager) ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("userManager");

if (userManager != null && userManager.isLoggedIn()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
}
```

Comment: However how should I implement this: "After a successful login user would be redirected to the page he wanted to reach initially, in this case a.html."?

Comment: Sorry, I understood that you already figured that part. You can use `ExternalContext#redirect()` to send a redirect in JSF.

Comment: @Koray: it continues the request processing.