# Best way to implement user login page in JSF

Tags: jsf

What's best way to implement login page in JSF 1.2? If session is timeout, use will be redirected to login in page.  i found 2 ways to do it on internet.

1. use PhaseListener ->
   http://www.jsfcentral.com/listings/A92000?link
2. use filter ->
   [What is the correct way to implement login with redirect using JSF 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526286/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-login-with-redirect-using-jsf-2-0).

also i want user go through an agreement page right after login page. user need to click on "agree" button to continue to use the system.

can anyone tell me which option is better or if there is a better way to implement this.

thank you,

Answer (score 2):

> What's best way to implement login page in JSF 1.2?

Just use a JSP/Facelet page with a `<h:form>` and appropriate input elements and a backing bean which puts the user in an injected session scoped bean.

> If session is timeout, use will be redirected to login in page. i found 2 ways to do it on internet.

Definitely use a `Filter`. A `PhaseListener` has too much overhead for this simple use case. You're not interested in filtering/modifying the JSF lifecycle, but just on filtering/modifying HTTP requests.

> also i want user go through an agreement page right after login page. user need to click on "agree" button to continue to use the system.

Well, then just develop such a page? If you stucks, press `Ask Question` on the right top with the actual problem described in detail.

Answer (score 0):

`Filter` is always better is meant for this, and more suitable also.

Now for your requirement ,

On successful Login
 - Add managedBean holding user info to session
On acceptance of terms
 - update this bean's field

- and check for both the condition for rest of the pages.
- no check on login page
- check of bean for term page

Answer (score 0):

In JSF2 it can be done using **System events**. In your template page put

```
< f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.checkLogin}"/>
```

and in loginBean ( make it session scoped ) you can do like this

```
public void checkLogin(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
// loggedIn is a boolean variable when sucessfully logged in make it true and at   logout  make it false.
if (!loggedIn) { 
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 ConfigurableNavigationHandler handler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)
 context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
 handler.performNavigation("login");
 }
}
```