# Basic steps for starting session in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

Can anyone please tell me the basic steps which are must to perform for creating new session in jsf?

Does a session scoped managed bean redirecting authentic user to some page create session?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *Can anyone please tell me the basic steps which are must to perform for creating new session in jsf?*

You don't need to do anything with regard to the HTTP session. The servletcontainer will create and manage it for you whenever the application requires so (e.g. whenever you're using a session scoped managed bean in JSF).

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)

---

> *Does a session scoped managed bean redirecting authentic user to some page create session?*

JSF doesn't offer builtin facilities to handle authentication. There are several options:

1. Homegrow it yourself. On login set the logged-in `User` as a property of a session scoped managed bean and let your application intercept on that.

   #### See also:

   - [JSF HTTP Session Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841361/jsf-http-session-login)
   - [How can I create a new session with a new User login on the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505328/how-can-i-create-a-new-session-with-a-new-user-login-on-the-application/)
   - [What is the correct way to implement login with redirect using JSF 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526286/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-login-with-redirect-using-jsf-2-0)
2. Use the Servlet API provided container managed authentication in combination with a wrapper managed bean.

   #### See also:

   - [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0)