# Creating session in JSF using tag

Tags: jsp, jsf, session, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic steps for starting session in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020994/basic-steps-for-starting-session-in-jsf)

Is there any Tag in JSF through we can create session and mantain it.I have seen the wonderful answers by [BalusC regarding sessions in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020994/basic-steps-for-starting-session-in-jsf).But can I do all this using a simple JSF tag? Or i have to put all the stuff in backing bean?

Comment: It look like that you're also looking in the wrong direction for the solution. You do not need to create/manage "the session" yourself at all. The container does it already for you. You just have to declare a session scoped managed bean and/or store/retrieve attributes in/from the session. Basically, your question is already answered by the link which you found yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of why you would want to do this is so you 
could bind input data to the session without needing to create a managed bean. This is possible.

This input field value binds to the `foo` property on the session:

```
<h:inputText value='#{sessionScope.foo}' />
```

But this is a false economy. If you want to act on this data you will likely need to inject it into a bean so your business logic can make use of it. Nothing is gained.

Comment: I dont want anything like that.. I want that if the user is authenticated his name should be present in the session...

Comment: Ah, you mean authenticating a user with the application somehow. There are many mechanisms available at both the container and application level. You would need to state which approach you are using - for example, the [Java EE 6 tutorial discusses a few of security options](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncat.html) available though its list is not exhaustive.